# How to store a server address and port in a string variable

Tags: c, sockets, serversocket

I'm creating a client/server socket and I need to get the sockets server IP using the sockaddr_in function **getsocketname()**. However, I'm not sure how to do this since I'm unable to do something like

```
struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
int IP = servAddr.getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *) %servAddr,sizeof(servAddr));
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some detail, like which OS and compiler is involved? Also, it would be helpful if the supplied code were more complete; such as a compilable program the includes main(), etc.

Comment: In C, structs can’t have member methods. There is no function `getsocketname()`. Do you mean [`getsockname()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe getsockname() is used for the client side, not server, and only once a connection has been made successfully using a socket to a server you defined.

To explain, a possible flow to connect a client to a server is:

1. Create a socketfd var, like 'sock' in your case
2. Open the socketfd var with a socket(...) call
3. Create your own variable to store the server details, let's say:

```c
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0"); // replace with actual server IP

    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(80); // replace with actual port
```

4. Connect sockfd to the server specified with serverAddr using a connect(...) call
5. Get the client side IP and port for this connection using a getsockname(...) call

```c
    getsockname(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr));
    
    char buffer[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; // stores the client side IP address

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientAddr.sin_addr, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    int port = (int) ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port); // stores the client side port
    
    printf("IP address: %s\n", buffer);

    printf("Port: %d\n", port);
```